# Where does the term 'board' come from in 'room and board'?

Tags: idioms

Where does the term 'board' come from when its used in the 'room and board' context?

Comment: Room is a place to sleep (on a bed, provided); board is a table to eat (food, provided). Room and board means a room with daily meal(s).

Comment: I think this is  General Reference. Wikipedia: ["Board" refers to the table on which food is served.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_and_board)

Answer (score 1):

boarding (n.) from *board*

> 1530s, "supplying of meals, food and lodging," from board (n.1) in its
>   extended sense of "food" (via notion of "table"). Boarding-school is
>   from 1670s; boarding house attested from 1728.

Source: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boarding&allowed_in_frame=0